# Let $B = \oplus_{d \in Z} B_d$ be a graded ring with $B$ generated by $B_1$ as a $B_0$-algebra. Then $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is locally free of rank $1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

You could view this question as asking about the proof of Proposition 5.12 (a) In Hartshorne's book, but written up in a different way.

So this is what I want to prove :

> Let $B = \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{Z}}B_d$ be a graded ring with $B$ generated by $B_1$ as a $B_0$-algebra and consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(d) = \widetilde{B(d)}$ on $\operatorname{Proj} B$. Then $\mathcal{O}(d)$ is locally free of rank $1$.

Now what follows below is my incomplete attempt to piece together a slightly modified version of the proof given in Hartshorne's book.

---

*Incomplete Proof:* To show this we need to show that for all $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Proj} B$, there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq \operatorname{Proj} B$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\mathcal{O}(d)|_U \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} B}|_U$.

First note that since $B$ is generated by $B_1$ as a $B_0$-algebra, this means that for all $b \in B$, there exists $b_{11}, \dots, b_{nm} \in B_1$ such that $b = \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m b_{ij}$ and this implies that $\operatorname{Proj} B = \bigcup_{a \in B_1} D_+(a)$.

Now choose $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Proj} B$ and consider the open set $D_+(a)$ where $a \in B_1$ and where $\mathfrak{p} \in D_+(a)$. Then we have by definition that $\mathcal{O}(d)|_{D_+(a)} = \widetilde{B(d)}|_{D_+(a)}$ and we see that, since $a \in B_1$ is homogenous, that $\widetilde{B(d)}|_{D_+(a)} \cong \widetilde{B(d)_{(a)}}$ by Proposition 5.11 in Hartshorne. Now we define $\psi : B(d)_{(a)} \to B_{(a)}$ by $\psi\left(\frac{b}{a^n}\right) = \frac{b}{a^{n+d}}$, then it turns out that $\psi$ is an isomorphism and hence we have that $B(d)_{(a)} \cong B_{(a)}$ and hence we see putting all this together that  $$\mathcal{O}(d)|_{D_+(a)} = \widetilde{B(d)}|_{D_+(a)} \cong \widetilde{B(d)_{(a)}} \cong \widetilde{B_{(a)}}....$$

---

Now if I can show that $\widetilde{B_{(a)}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} B}|_{D_+(a)}$ then I would be done, but I am not sure how I could do so. So my question is - how can I show that  $\widetilde{B_{(a)}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} B}|_{D_+(a)}$?

Comment: Hartshorne (II.2.5b) gives you that isomorphism.

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld Okay so then I know that $$\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj} B}|_{D_+(a)}$$ but then how do I conclude that $$\widetilde{B_{(a)}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}}?$$

Comment: That follows from the equivalence of categories Hartshorne is talking about in (II.5.5).

Comment: @KarlKroningfeld Ah, so then specifically is it because $$B_{(a)} \cong \Gamma (\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}, \widetilde{B_{(a)}} ) \cong \Gamma (\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}, \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}})$$ that we conclude that $$ \widetilde{B_{(a)}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B_{(a)}}?$$

Comment: Yes, that is right.